# Temporary ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a table that displays SQL data. I'm trying to only allow the user to edit an entry within a row *if* that value already exists somewhere in that column.

For example, if I tried to change the value "`Strawberry`" in the column "`Fruit`" to "`Grape`", when I click out of the text field, it should only keep the value "`Grape`", if it already exists within the column "`Fruit`". Otherwise, it should return to "`Strawberry`".

I am trying to accomplish this like so:

On `ng-focus`, I call `recordValue()`. This gets the entire row, the column, and the value, and sets it in a separate variable.

On `ng-blur`, I call `validateValue()`, and check all of my rows for

a) the original row index

b) to see if the value exists already in any row in the table

c) if it does, keep it, else revert to original value

(use the original row variable to replace edited row at original row index)

However, the row I pass is an `ng-model` of `row[column]` (value of a column in a row). This means that I can't have the original value of the row, because it will update the original data as I change it.

To solve this, I created a `$watch` on the data. If the value for `$scope.validated` was true, update the variable the table uses as a data source. Otherwise, don't. `$scope.validated` is set to false when `recordValue()` is called, and true after looping through `validateValue()` and finding the value, or resetting it.

The problem is, the data *still* updates so I can't revert the value because the original row doesn't exist; when I loop through the data source, only the updated row exists. I can't find the original row *to revert to*.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Am I doing something incorrectly?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="columnName in columnArray">{{columnName}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in filteredData">
        <td ng-repeat="columnName in columnArray">
            <input ng-model="row[columnName]" ng-focus="recordValue(row,row[column])" ng-blur="validateValue(row,column,row[column])">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.recordValue = function (row, val) {
        $scope.originalRow = row;
        $scope.originalValue = val;
        $scope.validated = false;
    };

    $scope.validateValue = function (row, column, val) {
        // row is the row of data the text field is in
        // column is column name at row
        // val is value at column in row(ng-model on $scope.data)
        var indexOfOriginalRow;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
            var currentRow = $scope.data[i];
            if (currentRow == $scope.originalRow) {
                console.log("found it!");
                indexOfOriginalRow = i;
            }
            else if (currentRow[column] == val) {
                $scope.validated = true;
                // the value was found, keep it as is
                return;
            }
        }
        $scope.validated = true;
        $scope.data[index][column] = $scope.originalValue;
    };

$scope.$watch("data", function () {
        if ($scope.validated) {
            $scope.filteredData = doStuffWithData($scope.data);
        }
    }, true);
```

Each row is an object within an array (the datasource). When the values change, I update the PARENT data source, but not the data source the table uses. Unfortunately, it seems as though the table's data source (filteredData) updates anyways.

This prevents me from resetting the value of the text field because the value is updated in the data source, so it seems like it already exists in the table. It appears to be a logical error, but it is difficult to conceptualize the table and variable data structure, so I can't find the error.

**UPDATE:**

Even when I *only* store the value, and not reference of the original row, the bigger problem is that the data still updates. The original row is useless because the new row is already in the data source, meaning it will be found, viewed as a pre-existing value, and allow anything you type. Very frustrating.

Comment: `ng-model` will update the value, can you could just update the value inside `validateValue()` instead of using `ng-model`?

Comment: I could, but I would have to refactor lots of code built around this functionality. I wasn't told ahead of time this was a desired feature, so I was unable to optimize for it. Otherwise, I wouldn't use `ng-model`.

Comment: Are you sure of the order of blur/focus being executed?  If so then you may just need to add an else so you only check for matching values if the row isn't the current one.  As it is now you will always set `$scope.validated = true;` because the new value will match the updated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to store the value of `row` in `$scope.originalRow` without binding them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will always set `$scope.validated = true` and return because you are checking the updated row with the updated value.  Try adding an else:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = $scope.data[i];
        if (currentRow == $scope.originalRow) {
            console.log("found it!");
            indexOfOriginalRow = i;
        } else if (currentRow[column] == val) { // ADDED ELSE
            $scope.validated = true;
            // the value was found, keep it as is
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to help, it still doesn't reset. The original row still isn't found. :(

Comment: Hard to debug, but have you made any other changes?  Try using `$index` to check for the original row and add `console.log` statements to ensure you can find it for testing.  If you can't find the original row that is probably a separate question.